# Running Python Script from Terminal Error

Tags: python, macos, terminal, runtime-error, dyld

I'm trying to run my Python script form the Terminal (I write the scripts in Sublime Text2 and I use a  Mac osx). This is by no means my first time running one as such but I keep on getting this error that I have never seen before, nor do I understand it:

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
    Referenced from: /Users/ronaldoisabeast/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
    Reason: image not found
```

The only two commands I wrote were:

```
    dhcp-18-111-122-239:~ ronaldoisabeast$ cd Desktop/
    dhcp-18-111-122-239:Desktop ronaldoisabeast$ python dicegame.py
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a look at the Python.

Comment: Did you tried to run Python at console, just typing **python**?

Answer (score 4):

```
 export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Putting that line in your `~/.bash_profile` (and restarting your terminal) might fix your issue